# Do shower doors for tiled openings have to fit the width exactly?

Tags: doors, shower, tile

So I just measured my cement board to cement board width and before tiling it is 4'11".  This is due to the pan instructions of putting the pan 'against' the frame.  The pan is cast iron covered in porcelain so I would not have to tile that.

I was thinking I could buy a standard shower door of 5" but the pan instructions screw that up.  Once tile is in, I am guessing 4 foot 10.5 inches is left.

Are there 5' shower doors you just cut down and the glass overlaps more?  What are some suggestions here? Last time I was at home depot, all the doors were of a fixed size.

Thanks.

Comment: If they fit exactly how would you ever get it to open, their is usually a gap at the door but a flange that’s covers the gap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many shower doors have adjustment built into the frame or stiles at the wall. Usually the door fastens to a box section with sits tightly into a 'C' section. Once the door is fitted and adjusted the box section is 'locked' into place by drilling holes into the box section through pre-drilled holes in the 'C' section. Small self tapping screws and plastic caps finish off the job.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Almost any such door has a range of adjustment or applicability, often in the form of panel lap. Tiled openings just aren't that precise. Look at the installation manuals for any models you like. They'll tell you what the range is.

For example, [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/DreamLine-Enigma-Air-56-in-to-60-in-x-76-in-Frameless-Sliding-Shower-Door-in-Brushed-Stainless-Steel-SHDR-64607610-07/300188035) specifically lists 56-60".

> Up to 4 in. of adjustment for width, if needed